# strg + alt not working properly in neovim

Tags: neovim

I am using a Keyboard with a german ISO layout (changed to from ansi a day ago).

In neovim I have the problem, that pressing strg+alt+somekey doesn't work. If i instead use altgr+somekey it works fine. This is only occuring in neovim, I've also tried commandpromt, powershell, browser, etc... Everywhere else I don't have any unusual behaviour.

What makes it weirder (to me at least), is, that if i try strg+alt+7 (which should be open curly braces {, neovim instead inputs ^_
For all the other cases, it simply leaves insert-mode. The symbol I did try to type instead is displayed in the bottom right corner of neovim (I don't know what is usually displayed there...)

Especially for the braces which are typed with the right hand, pressing altgr instead is pretty annoying, although its a workaround for now :(
Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem here? I did not have this problem a few days ago. I was switching some keyboards around, could that be the cause? All other keys seem to behave perfectly fine.
I'm not really using any personalization-mods, only show line numbers, and relativnumbers.